# Error while validating constraint odoo

Tags: python, python-2.7, constraints, odoo

I get this error and I don't know how to solve it:

[image]

My code:

```
@api.constrains('num_dossier')
def identify_same_num(self):
    for record in self:
    obj = self.search([('num_dossier','=',record.num_dossier),('arrondissement_id','=',record.arrondissement_id.id)])
    if obj:
        raise except_orm('Erreur')
```

For the database :

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('number_uniq', 'unique(number, company_id, journal_id, type)','Numéro de facture doit etre unique par company!'),
    ('num_dossier_uniq', 'unique(num_dossier,arrondissement_id)', 'Numéro de dossier doit etre unique par Arrondissement')
]
```

Comment: Can you write here the code of your constraint? It's bound to be a problem with the decorators or the parameters.

Comment: yes of course , i have write it in the answers there

Comment: You should have edited your question to include the code I asked you for, instead of writing it in an answer. Anyways, you have a `for` inside your constraint method, and its content is not tabulated, so that's giving you a Python error (unless you've pasted here wrong).

Comment: thanks for your comment , but i have not problem in tabulated

Comment: Does the error remain if you comment the `identify_same_num` method? By the way, I think the method is redundant if you add the SQL constraint, doesn't it?

Comment: when i comment the [identify_same_num] method i don't get the error , so how can i make the SQL constraint work !!

Comment: Do you have any records stored in the database which have the same combination of (num_dossier, arrondissement_id). If so, SQL constraint will not be created (log will show you a warning). To make it work you need to remove those duplicated records first (or modify the keys to make them unique).